# Unable to execute a prepared statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I'm unable to execute the following prepared statement ,

```
PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT sb.id,sb.category,sb.make,sb.name,sb.pic,rs.slot
FRO M studbike AS sb LEFT JOIN reservation AS rs ON
sb.id=rs.studbike_id AND sb.availability=1 AND rs.date=? WHERE
sb.studpoint_id=? ORDER BY category DESC,name DESC';
```

If I try to execute the prepared statement by:

```
SET @sid=1;@date1 ='2012-06-12';
EXECUTE stmt USING @sid,@date1;
```

I'm getting:

```
mysql> EXECUTE stmt1 USING @sid,@date1;
Empty set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS ;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                              |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect date value: '1' for column 'date' at row 1 |
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect date value: '1' for column 'date' at row 1 |
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'studpoint_id' at row 1    |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But i'm able to run it normally by giving some values in place of ? in select statement.

```
mysql> SELECT sb.id,sb.category,sb.make,sb.name,sb.pic,rs.slot
        FROM studbike AS sb LEFT JOIN reservation AS rs ON sb.id=rs.studbike_id
        AND sb.availability=1 AND  rs.date='2012-06-11' WHERE sb.studpoint_id=1
        ORDER BY category DESC,name DESC \ G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
      id: 2 category: 126-150
    make: bajaj
    name: pulser
     pic: test.gif
    slot: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
      id: 1 category: 100-125
    make: bajaj
    name: discover
     pic: test.gif
    slot: NULL 
    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

regards,
ravi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
EXECUTE stmt USING @sid,@date1;
```

Should be

```
EXECUTE stmt USING @date1,@sid;
```

Order matters....